# How to get array key from corresponding array value?

Tags: php, arrays

You can easily get an array value by its key like so: `$value = array[$key]` but what if I have the value and I want its key. What's the best way to get it?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You could use [`array_search()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to find the first matching key.

From the manual:

```
$array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');

$key = array_search('green', $array); // $key = 2;
$key = array_search('red', $array);   // $key = 1;
```

Answer (score 18):

You can use the **[`array_keys`](https://www.php.net/array_keys)** function for that.

**Example:**

```
$array = array("blue", "red", "green", "blue", "blue");
print_r(array_keys($array, "blue"));
```

This will get the key from the array for value `blue`

Comment: Is this really what the OP is looking for? I understood it differently (as a search for a *value*).

Comment: @Pekka: Let's what OP is looking for actually, hands up though :)

Comment: array_search and array_keys both work for me, however array_search does take out the extra step of having to grab the first value of the array returned by array_keys. So I will use array_search, but +1 to each of you as they are both good answers.

Comment: This gets all **KEYS** in array `$array` that contain `blue`.  Just FYI for future googlers like me.

Answer (score 5):

```
$arr = array('mango', 'orange', 'banana');
$a = array_flip($arr);
$key = $a['orange'];
```

Comment: Fastest - no comparison, just flip the values with keys.

Comment: array_flip is O(n); array_search is also O(n) but it stops when it finds the value.

Answer (score 0):

No really easy way. Loop through the keys until you find array[$key] == $value

If you do this often, create a reverse array/hash that maps values back to keys. Keep in mind multiple keys may map to a single value.

Comment: I agree with making a reverse map if you need to do many lookups, but there definitely is [an easy way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960066/best-way-to-get-array-key-from-value/2960083#2960083)

Comment: @barrycarter @ Michael_Mrozek, see array_flip

Answer (score 0):

Your array values can be duplicates so it wont give you exact keys. However the way i think is fine is like iterate over and read the keys