# How do i get the key of an array element if i only have the value?

Tags: php, arrays

How do i get the key of an array element if i only have the value?

So i have this array and i need the key of an email address with the value

```
$users_emails = array(
 'Spence' => 'spence@someplace.com', 
  'Matt'   => 'matt@someplace.com', 
  'Marc'   => 'marc@someplace.com', 
  'Adam'   => 'adam@someplace.com', 
  'Paul'   => 'paul@someplace.com');
```

How do i get the 'Adam' if all i have is the value 'adam@someplace.com'.. so basically how do i get the key if i have the value

Comment: Note that while keys are unique, values aren't. If you have multiple array entries with the same value, you'll have multiple keys as well.

Answer (score 3):

Use [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960066/best-way-to-get-array-key-from-value).

Example from docs:

```
<?php
$array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');

$key = array_search('green', $array); // $key = 2;
$key = array_search('red', $array);   // $key = 1;
?>
```

PHP has wonderful documentation and it's quite easy to find the basic stuff with Google.

```
<?php
$key = array_search('matt@someplace.com', $users_emails); // $key = 'Spence';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$email = 'adam@someplace.com';
$name = array_search($email, $users_emails);
var_dump($name === 'Adam');
```

See [array_search()](http://php.net/array-search)

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_search](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

```
$key = array_search('adam@someplace.com', $users_emails);
```